# How do I randomly classify my coordinate data in R

Tags: r, classification, data-generation

I have written a code that generates x and y data and am able to plot it.

```
# Number of observations
n <- 250
# x randomly drawn from a continuous uniform distribution with bounds [0,10]
x <- runif(min = 0, max = 1, n = sample(n))
# Error term from Normal distribution
error <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 2)
beta_0 <- 1
beta_1 <- -1
y <- beta_0*x + (beta_1*x - error)

library(tibble)
df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)
df

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() 
labs(title = "y = f(x)")
```

I get an graph image like this:

[image]

I also get a data table like this of different coordinate data:

| x | y. |
| --- | --- |
| 0.139 | -2.87 |
| 0.981 | 1.48 |

I would like to now randomly classify my data, such that my table looks like:

| x | y. | Group1 | Group2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.139 | -2.87 | -1 | 1 |
| 0.981 | 1.48 | 1 | -1 |

Where 1 represents that points membership to the group and -1 representing the point not being affiliated to the group. On the graph this would look like I had blue dots for Group1 membership vs red dots for Group2 membership.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you suggested (with one column for group 1 and one column for group 2), you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(group1 = sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE),
         group2 = -group1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(group1))) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer('group', palette = 'Set1', 
                     labels = c('Group 1', 'Group 2')) +
  labs(title = "y = f(x)")
```

[image]

However, it seems a bit redundant to me having two mutually exclusive binary columns. You could just have a single column called `group` which is either group 1 or group 2:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(group = sample(c('Group 1', 'Group 2'), n, TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  labs(title = "y = f(x)"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the help learning this. Now to spend more time with dplyr!